# Route Middleware validation

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a route which is:

```
Route::get('/{slug}',['as' => 'index', 'middleware' => 'player_group', 'uses' => 'PlayerController@index']);
```

What I am trying to do is check if the authenticated user is in {slug} group.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $user_grupo = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT id FROM user JOIN group ON group.id_ = user.id_group WHERE user.id = ".$user." AND group.slug = '".$slug."'") );;
    if (!$user_group) {
       //ERROR 
    } else { 
       return $next($request); 
    }
}
```

But thats not working... It is trowing an error:

```
Undefined variable: slug
```

Comment: can you post the contents of dd($request) please

Comment: Try `$request->route('slug');`

Comment: u got it Abbasi.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get parameters from route use `$request->route('slug');`